# Azure Container Service Container as a VSTS Agent to build docker images

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-container-service

I created ACS instance and registered it as a VSTS Agent. I used image `lenisha/vsts-agent-infrastructure` to use terraform. Anyway I want to build docker images, but using Agents from ACS I get error: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`. So question is if there is a way to get to docker daemon? I wasn't able to find info about how to mount docker.sock in ACS (`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refer to this blog on : [Using the Visual Studio Team Services Agent Docker Images](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/Using-the-VSTS-Docker-Agent/)

> Agent that supports using Containers to build source Finally, we come
>   to the part you are most interested in. How do we actually set up one
>   of these agents and avoid the above errors?
>
> There is an environment variable called `VSTS_WORK` that specifies
>   where the work should be done by the agent. We can change the location
>   of the directory and volume mount it so that when the docker container
>   runs on the host it will have access to the files.
>
> To create an agent that is capable of using docker in this way:
>
> ```
> docker run -e VSTS_ACCOUNT=<youraccountname>  \
>   -e VSTS_TOKEN=<your-account-Private-access-token> \
>   -e VSTS_WORK=/var/vsts -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
>   -v /var/vsts:/var/vsts -d \ microsoft/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-17.03.0-ce-standard
> ```
>
> The important command here is `-e VSTS_WORK=/var/vsts` which tells the
>   agent to do all the work in the `/var/vsts` folder. Then volume
>   mounting the folder with -v `/var/vsts:/var/vsts` enables you to run
>   docker containers inside the VSTS agent and still see all the files.

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on my research seems cannot find a way to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` from host machine inside ACS Container, such as the issue mentioned in this thread : [Mounting volume in Azure-Container-Service not working for traefik.toml and /var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463640/mounting-volume-in-azure-container-service-not-working-for-traefik-toml-and-var)

Comment: I have such setups on bare metal machines and it's ok. They run VSTS Agents as docker instances. Problem is rather with Azure Container Services. I don't know if its possible to mount /var/run/docker.sock from host machine inside ACS Container

Comment: @Mateusz Based on my research seems cannot find a way to mount  /var/run/docker.sock from host machine inside ACS Container, such as this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463640/mounting-volume-in-azure-container-service-not-working-for-traefik-toml-and-var

Comment: I think you are right. Could you post it as answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Mateusz Updated the answer :)